# Number of rows in a partition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas

I have a daily partition in a measure group in my SSAS cube.

While doing my UAT, I noticed that the process may have run before the data load in the underlying database was fully done, which is why totals do not match.

How can I count the number of rows that were actually read into a partition when it was processed?

Answer (score 2):

Processing a partition sends some messages back, among these the information how many rows were processed. Depending on the tool used to process the partition, this information may be logged somewhere. You can see this information e. g. if you start the processing the partition in BIDS or Management Studio: A text like "Processing Partition 'Internet_Sales_2001' completed. 1013 rows have been read." is displayed.

After processing, you could use the following **undocumented** way of finding the number of records in a partition if you have administrator access to the machine running Analysis Services: On the Analysis Services server, find the directory containing the data (in a default installation this would be something like `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS10.<instancename>\OLAP\Data`. Then, you have a directory per database ending in `.db`, within that one per cube ending in `.cub`, within that one per measure group ending in `.det`, and within that one per partition ending in `.prt`. In this directory, open the file `info.xml`. This contains an element `<m_cRecord>`, which seems to contain the record count. Sometimes, the number is slightly less that the number of records read as shown in the message described above. I assume this is an optimization of Analysis Services omitting empty rows, but I am not sure.

And, of course, all this is without warranties, as it is undocumented and just a guess. And you should be careful and never manually edit any of these files.